# will using a ventilation system with an heat exchanger give me the same quality air indoors as outdoors?

Tags: hvac, ventilation, air-quality

will using a ventilation system with an heat exchanger give me the same quality air indoors as outdoors?

is using a proper ventilation system equivalent to having all your windows open without any heat loss in terms of the air quality (namely the freshness/crispness of air)

Comment: [Combining Air Conditioner with Air Purifier](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/61847/combining-air-conditioner-with-air-purifier) - It's not even close even with a HVR *and* a TFP. Anytime you can just use a whole house fan, you should be. When it's 70f outside and I hear my neighbor's AC kick on... I guess they just like paying for stuff. A box fan is like 1 amp. An AC compressor is like 20+, *and* there's *two* fans anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A heat-recovery ventilator will give you mostly what you want, though how much you get depends on how big it is and how much it runs.

Answer (score 1):

> will using a ventilation system with an heat exchanger give me the same quality air indoors as outdoors?

No, external air only mixes with internal one, flow rate volume is given in tech details of the unit and that determines, how much of the exchange happens. Effective set up will be close to air outside.

> is using a proper ventilation system equivalent to having all your windows open

depending on volume of air exchanged, it can be better or worse - taking in consideration: co2, o2, moisture

if units use hepa filters then air will always be better, taking into consideration particles filtered out by filter [dust, allergens etc]